# How to add a script to launch bar?

Tags: launcher, .desktop

From multiple topics on this forum I distilled the following approach:

- copy an existing `.desktop` file from `/usr/share/applications` to `~/.local/share/applications`
- manipulate the file to your needs
- give the file executing rights
- hit windows key to open up available applications
- type the specified name in the newly copied  `.desktop` file, and drag it to launcher bar

Any wrong conclusions/interpretations in the above?

This is my changed `.desktop` file, with `chmod +x` attributes, sitting in `~/.local/share/applications`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=RPD Work
Categories=GTK;GNOME;X-GNOME-NetworkSettings;Network;
Keywords=rdp; remote desktop; work;
Exec=~/rdp.sh work
Icon=org.remmina.Remmina
MimeType=application/x-remmina;x-scheme-handler/remmina;x-scheme-handler/rdp;x-scheme-handler/spice;x-scheme-handler/vnc;
```

When I type 'rdp' or 'remote desktop', only the existing original remmina icon appears, my personal creation never shows up.

What am I doing wrong (and why is this so complicated.... am I following the wrong approach here?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom `.desktop` laucher will appear in the application overview only when it is valid. The issue here is that you are assuming that all bash expansions and substitutions work from within a .desktop launcher: that is not the case. Thus, in your `Exec=` line, replace `~/rdp.sh` by the full path, i.e. `/home/<yourlogin/rpd.sh`. As far as I see, that will be the only issue with your current file.

Note that there is no need to make the .desktop file executable.

Why it is complicated? Old tools that allowed to do this through a GUI have been dropped, but tools like "Libremenu" or "Alacarte" can still be installed through the software center if you need this on a regular basis. "Complicated" is a relative term. You may quickly find it faster to edit a .desktop file than to click around in Libremenu.

Comment: The name field should also be corrected like this: `Name=RDP Work`

Comment: Yeah found that as well. But had some more keywords that should have made it appear. The main issue was indeed the path thing. It works now. Thx